# LAG(offset) until value is reached in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

Is it somehow possible to use `LAG()` in BigQuery in such a way that it continues until a certain value or condition is met? In other words, I need the `offset` to be dynamic based on the number of rows to jump.

For example:

```
#standardSQL
WITH input AS (
  SELECT 1 AS id, 1 AS col_1, 'A' AS col_2 UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 AS id, 0 AS col_1, 'B' AS col_2 UNION ALL
  SELECT 3 AS id, 0 AS col_1, 'C' AS col_2 UNION ALL
  SELECT 4 AS id, 1 AS col_1, 'D' AS col_2 UNION ALL
  SELECT 5 AS id, 1 AS col_1, 'E' AS col_2 UNION ALL
  SELECT 6 AS id, 0 AS col_1, 'F' AS col_2 UNION ALL
  SELECT 7 AS id, 1 AS col_1, 'G' AS col_2 )
```

If `col_1` equals 0, then take the value of `col_2` where the **last** preceding `col_1` equals 1.

Desired output:

[image]

I could do it with self joins, but I'd rather avoid using joins if possible i.e. there has to be a smarter way!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BigQuery Standard SQL

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH input AS (
  SELECT 1 AS id, 1 AS col_1, 'A' AS col_2 UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 AS id, 0 AS col_1, 'B' AS col_2 UNION ALL
  SELECT 3 AS id, 0 AS col_1, 'C' AS col_2 UNION ALL
  SELECT 4 AS id, 1 AS col_1, 'D' AS col_2 UNION ALL
  SELECT 5 AS id, 1 AS col_1, 'E' AS col_2 UNION ALL
  SELECT 6 AS id, 0 AS col_1, 'F' AS col_2 UNION ALL
  SELECT 7 AS id, 1 AS col_1, 'G' AS col_2 
)
SELECT id, col_1, col_2,
  IF(col_1 = 0, FIRST_VALUE(col_2) OVER(PARTITION BY grp ORDER BY col_1 DESC), NULL) AS col_3 
FROM (
  SELECT * ,
    SUM(col_1) OVER(ORDER BY id) AS grp
  FROM input
)
-- ORDER BY id
```

Comment: Completely missed the `FIRST_VALUE` function in the docs. Thanks Mikhail!